# How to use Guard Clauses with Stateless

Tags: c#, .net, stateless-state-machine

I'm new to using [Stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless)  and trying to make sure I understand the purpose of a guard clause. I'm able to create a state machine, but I want to essentially put a check on entering the state where the age > 12 && parent permission exists. Am I understanding Guard clause correctly, and if  so, how would I implement such a clause?

```
    var stateMachine = new StateMachine<State, Trigger>(State.EnrollmentCompleted);

    stateMachine.Configure(State.EnrollmentCompleted)
                .Permit(Trigger.EnrollmentCompleted,ValidatingEnrollment, ***Guardclause to check if user age > 12 and Parentpermission=true***);

    return stateMachine;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is information on Guard clauses on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless). Based on that, it looks like it would just be...

```
stateMachine.Configure(State.EnrollmentCompleted)
            .Permit(Trigger.EnrollmentCompleted,ValidatingEnrollment, () => userAge > 12 && parentpermission);
```